# How to send DM to command author?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that sends the user who entered the command a DM, but I don't get an error code in PyCharm or a DM in Discord when I enter the command. Am I doing something wrong?

```
@client.command(aliases=['manage'])
async def oversee(message):
    await message.author.send('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Do you by chance have an on_message event?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), when you create a command using the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) framework, your first argument **must** be `ctx`:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['manage'])
async def oversee(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send('Hello World!')
```

Your function would work as intended if it was a `on_message` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!manage") or message.content.startswith("!oversee"):
        await message.author.send('Hello World!')
```

However, I don't recommand using `on_message` events to create commands, using the `commands` framework will be way easier and more efficient.